# how to query data between AM and PM varchar time in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have date and time stored as 2 columns in MySQL table using type varchar. Time format is 12 hour format (11:59:59 am, 12:59:59 pm, 01:59:59 pm, etc.) as in attached files.

[image][image]

I'd like to query to get data between 11:13:00 am and 12:13:59 pm. The query I used as

`` SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date = '10-09-2021' and ((time BETWEEN '11:13:00 am' and '11:59:59 am') or (time BETWEEN '12:00:00 pm' and '12:13:59 pm')) ``

It give me all data including pm data like 11:20:23 pm in attached files. Please advise how to query. Alternative way is I'd like to get data within 1 hour range. Thank you.

Comment: "I have date and time stored as 2 columns in MySQL table using type `varchar`." - **that's awful** - who designed the database like that? Have they apologized to you in-person and committed ritual seppuku for their _shame_? If not, **why not?**

Comment: I do not get this, because `11:20:23` is between the times you used in the query ....

Comment: Thanks. It's not working as desired. Still include PM value. If I have 11:00:00 AM and 11:00:00 PM, I'd like to get AM data that not include PM data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query on pure varchar type, it needs to filter am/pm

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `date` = '10-09-2021' 
AND ((`time` LIKE '% am' AND `time` BETWEEN '11:13:00 am' and '11:59:59 am') OR (`time` LIKE '% pm' AND `time` BETWEEN '12:00:00 pm' and '12:13:59 pm'))
```

to query one hour range,

```
`time` LIKE '11:% am'
```

Other option is to convert the varchar time to a date using STR_TO_DATE(), and use standard between ... and ... , side effect is that you probably cannot use the table index on the column.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "cannot use the table index"; converting to a datetime will make it more possible to use an index, not less

Comment: I mean to do date conversion in the query itself, not modifying the table schema.